# IF in xslt file

Tags: xml, xslt

i need help to write condition of xslt file
i have something like this:

```
<some_tag style="blank">ten</some_tag>
<some_tag style="p">some text here </some_tag>
<some_tag style="p">some other text here </some_tag>


<some_tag style="blank">two</some_tag>
<some_tag style="pi">some text here </some_tag>
 ....
```

xslt must check, if `style="blank"` contains "ten" change style value of next tag to "value_+10",     elsif contains two, change  style value of next tag to "value_+2"

something like this

```
 <div class="blank"> ten </div>
 <p class="p_10">some text here</p>
 <p class="p"> some other text here</p>

 <div class="blank"> two </div>
 <p class="pi_2">some text here</p>
```

thank you and sorry if i write something wrong

Comment: Please share some code you've written in XSLT

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: didn't  write any code yet, only interest if i can write it with xslt, i made this by ruby script

Answer (score 0):

As I assume that you already have some XSLT, just an example you can adjust to work for your requirements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="some_tag[@style='blank']">
 <div class="{@style}">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="some_tag[./preceding-sibling::some_tag/.[@style='blank']][@style!='blank']">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(normalize-space(./preceding-sibling::some_tag[1]), 'ten') ">
     <p class="{@style}_ten">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </p> 
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(normalize-space(./preceding-sibling::some_tag[1]), 'two') ">
    <p class="{@style}_two">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <p class="{@style}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <some_tag style="blank">ten</some_tag>
 <some_tag style="p">some text here </some_tag>
 <some_tag style="p">some other text here </some_tag>
 <some_tag style="blank">two</some_tag>
 <some_tag style="pi">some text here </some_tag>
</root>
```

Output XML:

```
<root>
  <div class="blank">ten</div>
  <p class="p_ten">some text here </p>
  <p class="p">some other text here </p>
  <div class="blank">two</div>
  <p class="pi_two">some text here </p>
</root>
```

And regarding your question how to use `<xsl:if>` - it's used in a similar way like `<xsl:when>`, but as this approach works using `<xsl:choose>` to test for `ten` and for `two`, an `<xsl:if>` wasn't necessary.

Reference for `<xsl:if>` : http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:if

Comment: it give me `XPath error : Invalid expression
./preceding-sibling::some_tag/.[@style='blank']` in code that i copy